# Workflow Error in FileNet P8 4.5

Tags: filenet-p8

I am receiving this error intermittently when running a workflow in FileNet P8 4.5. The step where I get this error has two CE operations - "createFolder" and "applySecurityTemplate". I have not been able to trace the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Work Performer Exception: <Server Name - name removed>com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException;An error was returned from the server. A Web services request received a non-HTTP response.  Response contents: maxRecursion="2">Id</IncludeProperties></PropertyFilter></ObjectRequest></GetObjectsRequest></e:Body></e:Envelope> 400 Bad Request<CRLF>Connection: close [Code=null] ... Object Reference [OBJECT_STORE:4] ID "{210A5F13-CA1A-44D6-808F-CA763C882BDA}" in ObjectStore "{210A5F13-CA1A-44D6-808F-CA763C882BDA}"; OMFC/Library/GetProperties//E_SERVER_ERROR

Root Cause:
An error was returned from the server. A Web services request received a non-HTTP response.  Response contents: maxRecursion="2">Id</IncludeProperties></PropertyFilter></ObjectRequest></GetObjectsRequest></e:Body></e:Envelope> 400 Bad Request<CRLF>Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a PMR, IBM asked us to start component manager from /opt/FileNet/WebClient/Router/routercmd.sh and change the CE URI to FNCEWS40MTOM from the existing FNCEWS40DIME and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions first:

1. Are you using the CE_Operations component adapter (CA) or the WS_Request adaptor?
2. Do these component adapter EVER work, or do they only fail with this workflow?

Troubleshooting CA issues can be tough. Here's basically what you can do:

- Dial-up logging of the Component Manager and look at the resulting logs. They can be a bit difficult to read (like any debug log), but they will give you more information.
- Write a super-simple workflow that tests the use case that is failing.

Also, since these seems to be a web service-related issue, you may want to install a sniffer (like ethereal) to see what is being passed back and forth.

HTH!

Tom Purl

Comment: The workflow was creating a folder and applying a security template on it. Figured security template application on folders is not allowed through WF! So we removed that portion. But the Workflow still fails intermittently while creating the folder. Uptil now, I have found that this error means no information is being returned from the server (properties are queried on the server before the folder is created). Why, I do not know yet. But error happens only when there is more than one folder to be created in the CE operation. The logs don't have much info. I don't know of any adapters.